# Fill image with different color by detecting the different parts

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I have an Image of a landscape which i need to fill with different colors.

When i select colors from palette and start scrubbing on any particular part, only that part should get the color even if by mistake i take my finger outside of that image part.

So basically i need to detect which part of image have i tapped so that only that part takes the color.

I am developing this app in Cocos2dx, but any help in logic would be a good point to start.

Here is an example of what i want.

Note : I know i could achieve this by taking separate images and then detecting touches, but that increases the app size by alot of MB's.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess user will be able to draw only on white part of the image.
If above is true, what i want you to do is, in your touchesMoved method, check if any black color (non white) pixel is present between previous touch point and current touch point.
If there is no such black pixel, then draw it else dont draw it.

Comment: yea,i tried that, but when you take you finger out of the "heart" in above image , it will still fill the color as it doesnt have black pixel there too.So essentially t comes down to detecting whether our finger has gotten into some other enclosed part of image.

Comment: I didn't get what you said. Lets say the user had his finger down at centre of the heart.So, if he now moves his finger towards nose of the cartoon, while moving touchesMoved method will be called,and each time you query whether the " **line segment** joining last touch point and current touch point" has any black pixels.Initailly there would be no such point, but when he comes near the edge of heart and crosses the black border of heart, we would get a black pixel.That indicates user is moving out of heart part of image. Am iam thinking straight?

Comment: Case1: the case which you said is correct, but for example if the user is scrubbing inside the heart image and in case by mistake touches the edge of the heart outline, in that by your code, it would stop coloring in touchesMoved, and will have to again tap inside the heart image to continue filling color.

Comment: Case 2 : even if the user does not tap the black outline and intentionally wants to take his finger out, in that case as per you i will discontinue drawing, but remember my finger is still in touchesMoved mode and then if the user wishes to come inside the heart image start filling again, it wont let it to so as we have already discontinued filling the color.